# How to have cells dynamically populate based on start and length

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

Basically, the problem is summarized by the picture below.

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8YzR.jpg

The "Start" column is when the beginning of "Descriptor" variable starts and it populates the number of rows starting according to the value in the "Length" column that starts from the "Start" column.

Solving this using values is simple on a small dataset such as the example but how would it be replicated using formula?

Thanks,

Comment: The logic here is if the (base 1) horizontalcell index is greater than or equal to the start number and less than the start number plus the length, then show the descriptor, else blank. Should be able to put this in an excel formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Bryan60 his answer is nice and clear!

For the sake of alternatives, in cell`D2`:

```
=IF(D$1=MEDIAN(D$1,$A2,$A2+($B2-1)),$C2,"")
```

Or when the numbers on the top are not there:

```
=IF(COLUMN(A1)=MEDIAN(COLUMN(A1),$A2,$A2+($B2-1)),$C2,"")
```

Drag down and right.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Something like this in cell D2, then drag as needed.

```
=IF(AND(COLUMN()-3>=$A2,COLUMN()-3<$A2+$B2),$C2,"")
```

just noticed the numbers up top, so this is also workable:

```
=IF(AND(D$1>=$A2,D$1<$A2+$B2),$C2,"")
```

Comment: Or when the numbers on top are there: `=IF(AND(D$1>=$A2,D$1<$A2+$B2),$C2,"")`